# Can't get Cypress to execute after hook

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, hook, cypress

I'm trying to delete something I use in my suite of tests, using the after hook but the hook is never executed.

```js
describe("here I start the suite", function() {
    
  before(() => {
    cy.storeIDs();
  });

  after(() => {
    cy.removeIDs();
  });

  it("here I execute my tests", function() {
    cy.processFile();
  });

});   // end of describe
```

The suite of tests, included the before hook (executed once before all tests) runs perfectly. It does not matter what I write inside the after hook, I never get it to execute.
I know cypress documentation does not recommend using the after hook but in this case I have no choice. Any ideas as to why I can't get it to run? Even with a cy.log() inside and no actual code, it does not get to run :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You refer to this section [Using after or afterEach hooks](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/best-practices#Using-after-or-afterEach-hooks), where it is suggests doing cleanup in `before()` instead of `after()`

```js
before(() => {
  if (getIds()) {   // if needed check ids exist first
    cy.removeIDs()
  })
  cy.storeIDs()
})
```

---

However, if you still want to use `after()`, be aware that asynchronous commands will still run but ***will not cy.log()***.

For example,

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('removeIds', () => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('cleanup')  // ✅ logs to dev console, so this has run
    cy.log('cleanup')     // ❌ does not log to Cypress log 
  }, 1000)
})

after(() => {
  cy.log('after - #1')  // ✅ logs to Cypress log 
  cy.removeIds()
})
```

To get that final `cy.log()`, try using a `.then()`

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('removeIds', () => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('cleanup')  // ✅ logs to dev console, so this has run
    cy.log('cleanup')     // ❌ does not log to Cypress log 
  }, 1000)
})

after(() => {
  cy.log('after - #1')  // ✅ logs to Cypress log 
  cy.removeIds().then(() => {
    cy.log('after - #2')  // ✅ logs to Cypress log, 
                          // ❢ but occurs before cy.removeIds() completes
  })
})
```

Or to cy.log() success of `removeIds`, return a promise

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('removeIds', () => {
  return new Cypress.Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve('ids removed')
    }, 1000)
  })
})

after(() => {
  cy.removeIds().then(msg => {
    cy.log(msg)  // ✅ logs 'ids removed' to Cypress log
  })
})
```